# Custom AdBlock Filter Not Working

Tags: html, css-selectors, ads, custom-lists, adblock

Why does the set of Adblock filters below not block the "Turn off your ad blocker" elements on [The Weather Channel](https://www.weather.com) website?

*Note: To display message, open page in a fresh private, incognito, or guest window with an ad blocker enabled.*

```
<div class="sp_veil1516388766878" style="display: block"></div>
<div id="sp_message_id1516388766878" class="sp_message_container1516388766878" style="display: block;">
```

Filters:

```
weather.com##div[class^="sp_veil"]
weather.com##div[class^="sp_message_container"]
```

I expected the ad blocker to remove both elements since the `class` values start with `sp_veil` and `sp_message_container`.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the filter working using uBlock Origin ([plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en),
 [website](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)). Explanation included in comments.

```
! Block dark transparent veil and message
weather.com##div[class^="sp_veil"]
weather.com##div[class^="sp_message_container"]

! Enable scrolling (page disables) it for message
weather.com#$#html {overflow-y: visible !important}
weather.com#$#html {height: auto !important}
weather.com#$#html {height: auto !important}
```